# Webpages render broken. Nextjs 13 on Digital Ocean

Tags: next.js, digital-ocean

The pages of my next.js website look like a strings of code when I get there directly. No errors in the Console (Chrome, Safari, no cache). It may or may not work normal when navigating from the homepage.

Nextjs 13 website. Using app router. Deployed to the server (digitalocean).

```
1:HL["/_next/static/media/3876a0f72c3984e0-s.p.woff2",{"as":"font","type":"font/woff2"}]
2:HL["/_next/static/media/8a2807d88ac56020-s.p.woff2",{"as":"font","type":"font/woff2"}]
3:HL["/_next/static/media/d9b920ce8a984259-s.p.woff2",{"as":"font","type":"font/woff2"}]
4:HL["/_next/static/css/fdd13217d4859704.css",{"as":"style"}]
0:[[["",{"children":["soft-ice",{"children":["__PAGE__",{}]}]},"$undefined","$undefined",true],"$L5",[[["$","link","0",{"rel":"stylesheet","href":"/_next/static/css/fdd13217d4859704.css","precedence":"next"}]],["$L6",["$","meta",null,{"name":"next-size-adjust"}]]]]]
7:HL["/_next/static/css/92be51721d315283.css",{"as":"style"}]
...
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYBKG.png)

Errors are not occur locally in dev or build/start mode.

I also noticed that the only page is working — is the one that you open first after the build on the server. You can navigate from that page to others and all goes well. But you can't go to other pages directly.

Could anyone point out the possible source of the problem?

I expected the problems with the layout.tsx caused by Navbar that used useRouter and usePathname. I removed them but it doesn't help. Also I wrapped Navbar into Suspension.

Comment: **UPD** More details of the strange behaviour. Any page that I open directly (via address bar) after deployment renders good next time to. Any page that was first time opened via navigation through the website — fails to be rendered next time when opened directly

Comment: UPD2. The content that comes to the browser instead of the full html is RSC (React Server Components). I located the `.rsc` files in `.next` directory on the server alongside with normal `.html` files. So somehow server decided to serve `.rsc` for given page all the time

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem found

Recent version of Next.js cache all requests. To clarify expected results of the request (html or rsc) it uses Vary headers. This Vary header is not recognized by many of CDN because of misconfiguration on the CDN side (it affects Digital Ocean, Cloudfire, and others).

### Solution

I moved from Digital Ocean to Vercel which works just fine with this feature (since nextjs is a product of Vercel). My relationships with DO are not so tight so it is not problem for me. Below are couple of other solutions that I found.

### Other solution

Found **but didn't try**: switch from App Router configuraion of the project to Page Router

### Links

1. https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/48569
2. https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/49140